# After uninstall, steam still asks to be installed

Tags: steam, software-uninstall

Steam was installed via the `steam.deb` on the website, then uninstalled. Still, each newly created user gets asked to

> Start Steam to complete installation of the Steam for the current user.

upon first login.

How to remove this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As told in [this forum post](https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/steam-laesst-sich-nicht-komplett-deinstalliere/), steam did not uninstall completely. It left the files `/var/lib/update-notifier/user.d/steam-install-notify` and `/usr/share/app-install/desktop/steam:steam.desktop` on the hard drives. The former contained the text. Removing it via

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/update-notifier/user.d/steam-install-notify
```

seems to solve the problem.